# Mean Squared Error for point estimation

Tags: variance, expected-value, mse, bias-variance-tradeoff, point-estimation

I am attempting to understand Mean Squared Error when evaluating point estimators for particular parameters of interest. The book we are reading for class states the following:

The mean squared error (MSE) of an estimator $W$ of a parameter $\theta$ is the function $\theta$ defined by
$$
E_{\theta} (W-\theta)^2 = \text{Var}_{\theta}W + (E_{\theta} W - \theta)^2=\text{Var}_{\theta} W + (\text{Bias}_{\theta} W)^2
$$

Where we define the bias of an estimator as follows:

$$\text{Bias}_{\theta} W = E_{\theta}W-\theta$$

An estimator whose bias is identically (in $\theta$) equal to $0$ is called unbiased and satisfies $E_{\theta}W=\theta$ for all $\theta$.

> For an unbiased estimator, we have $E_{\theta} (W-\theta)^2 = \text{Var}_{\theta}W$, and so if an estimator is unbiased its MSE is equal to its variance.

I am confused as to why we are just left with the variance of the estimator when the estimator is unbiased. I think this is due to variability that may come from the sample from which we are computing our estimator, but I am not 100% sure if this is the right thinking.

Comment: I know where it comes from in the formula, but my question is asking more about how the variance part is derived in the MSE formula.

Comment: Do you just want a derivation of the identity?

Comment: I cannot understand this bit: *The mean squared error (MSE) of an estimator $W$ of a parameter $\theta$ is the function $\theta$*. How come $\theta$ is both the parameter and the function? There must be a word missing or something.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\text{MSE}=(\text{bias})^2+\text{var}.
$$

An unbiased estimator has $\text{bias}=0$.

$$\begin{align}
\text{MSE}&=0^2+\text{var}\\\implies
\text{MSE}&=\text{var}.\end{align}
$$

Comment: I know I could count on the CV Crew to clean up the TeX I didn’t type out on mobile!